# Is it possible to get detailed error information for failed sends?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, dataextensions

My app invokes the SOAP API to send transactional messages using a triggered send and a SendLog data extension.  To track the status of messages, I use query activities to join the Send, Open, and Bounce data views with the SendLog data extension.  Occasionally, sends that are accepted in the send API call fail during the actual send.  Those sends never end up in any of the data views, but they end up in the SendLog data extension with an ErrorCode > 0.

Is there any way to get more detail about why these sends have failed?  The error codes are fairly broad, making it difficult to provide feedback to end-users.  I'm able to get detailed bounce information using the _Bounce data view, but these sends never get to that point.

Here's the reference page for the send error codes - http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/email_messages/email_send_error_codes/

The types of errors I'm seeing are ErrorCode=20 which has the name "Invalid Field Value" and the description "The value specified for a data extension field does not match the field type".  Is there any way to know which field?

Likewise, I'm seeing ErrorCode=24 which has the name "List Detective Exclusion" and the description "The subscriber was excluded by List Detective."  I'd like to know why the subscriber was excluded.

Answer (score 3):

Details about these things are generally scant.  SFMC Support and certain partners have access to a server error log.  Sometimes it will give you insights into Data Extension field value errors.

I doubt you'll get much info on List Detective exclusions. It's the secret sauce/spam trap blacklist the SFMC uses.  It may be worth a call to SFMC Support to see what they say.

There's also a [Not Sent Tracking Extract](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/data_extract_activity/extract_types/tracking_extract/tracking_extract_output/notsent/) and the canned [Subscribers Not Sent Report](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/tracking/reports/subscribers_not_sent_to_report/) that'll give you some more of this info.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Adam.  Regarding list detective, specifically:  http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/list_detective/

Main things about list detective:

An LD exclusion usually means a known spam trap or a known bad domain(phishing domains in particular).   It cannot be disabled(its there for protection of your sending reputation and SMC).  It runs on import to a list, or on sending to a data extension.  And, as Adam said,  It is proprietary, so we cant hand out information about how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I appreciate the need to keep the secret recipe a secret, but is there a process in place for reviewing individual subscribers?  If, for example, we confirm through other channels that an address is in fact valid, can that address be white-listed for future sends?

Comment: You can create a support case - our deliverability team would have to investigate any potential list detective errors, but the burden of proof would be pretty high.   

Custom list detective implementations are a thing as well, although there might be a cost associated, and that is generally to make list detective *more* restricted, not less.